# Python 2.7 > 3.5 JSON dumps "is not a string"

Tags: python, string, migration, byte

I am converting my code from Python 2.7 to 3.5 but run into some issues while dumping JSON data into a file.

Originally the code for 2.7 was like this:

```
backlog_json = json.dumps(backlog, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
f = open(backlog_path,"wt")
f.write(backlog_json)
f.close()
```

Currently the same code gives the following error:

```
TypeError: key b'00c4349c-9617-42c3-a0a3-8e16262bcd76' is not a string
```

It seems to do something with bytes, while I just want all items in my JSON to be strings.

for some reason `b'` is added to the dict data:

```
b'f91de40f-cf15-4da6-bee9-0101920c8874':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert any keys that are byte literals with strings. you can make the swap-with `str(bytes_string, 'utf-8')` but first you have to find them. If it is obvious where these byte literals exist you can write code to switch them out or you could convert like this...

```
def reqked(ob):
    if(type(ob) == dict):
        for(k in ob.keys()):
            if(type(k) == bytes):
                ob[str(k, 'utf-8')] = reqked(ob[k])
                del ob[k]
            else:
                ob[k] = reqked(ob[k])
    elif(type(ob) == list):
        for k in range(0,len(ob)):
            ob[k]=reqked(ob[k])
    elif(type(ob) == bytes):
        ob = str(bytes_string, 'utf-8')
    return(ob)
```

Comment: `backlog_info2[str(k,'utf-8')] = v
TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: so If I type some of the vars, they are already strings...

`<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>`

How come they still have a b' in front of them? :|

Comment: thank you, so I did str(bytes_data, 'utf-8' before adding it to the dict and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your byte data into string one

```
file = open(file_name, encoding='utf8')
json_data = json.load(file)
file.close()
```

Comment: thank you jesugmz, so how do I know there are bytes values in my code? So I know which I have to do this to?

Comment: basically is how `open` works, as the documentation says  _[...] the bytes having been first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified encoding if given[...]_ and you were not giving an encoding so it was trated as str-byte like. Also you can check the data type with [type()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#type).

Comment: thank you, so I did str(bytes_data, 'utf-8' before adding it to the dict and now it works :)